# Find numbers in an Array starting with a specific digit

Tags: java, arrays, performance

Looking for ideas for efficient solution(i know looping is required here) to finding the number starting with a specific digit in an Array.
If multiple numbers tarts with a digits, return smallest one found.
eg - 
Array - [1234,1235,1236,43232,12443,5646334,1231412,6798796,8987]

A function to have signature similar to *fun(array, statingDigit)*
Returns 43232 on inputting (array, 4)
Returns 1234 on inputting (array, 1)

Answer (score 5):

Using streams:

```
int[] array = {1234,1235,1236,43232,12443,5646334,1231412,6798796,8987};
OptionalInt match = Arrays.stream(array)
    .filter(p -> String.valueOf(p).startsWith("1"))
    .sorted()
    .findFirst();

if (match.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(match.getAsInt());
}
else {
    System.out.println("No matching number found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a `for` loop:

```
private static int fun(int[] array, String startingDigit) {
    int num = array[0];
    for (int i : array)
        if (i < num && Integer.toString(i).startsWith(startingDigit))
            num = i;
    return num == array[0] ? -1 : num;
}
```